# In Deferred Rendering would it be practical to replace the texture buffers with a material and UV buffer?

Tags: graphics, rendering, deferred

I tried putting all I could into the question but here's the flesh of it,

Would it be practical to make a deferred renderer which instead of having a Diffuse / Specular Buffer it had a Material / UV Buffer, The Materials would be handled similar to tiled light culling, the shader would be passed the required textures (specular, diffuse, glow, decal, etc. etc.) and sample them using the UVs in the UV buffer.

I was just trying to think of a way to get the benefits of deferred rendering and the flexibility of forward rendering, I couldn't think of a reason why this would get the worst of both, but I'm not able to find any information on anything similar so I don't know what its pros and cons are in practicality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't how this method would be an improvement on normal deferred rendering. The main disadvantages of deferred rendering are passing large buffers, complications of multiple lighting models, transparency and anti-aliasing.

Your proposed method would require huge buffers to store all the different textures for all your models, which would take up much more space than a diffuse and specular buffer.

Your method would make no improvement on lighting models as it would still require a material ID buffer and a complex shader for lighting.

Your method would not solve transparency or anti-aliasing.

Overall, a material and uv buffer could easily be replaced by just a diffuse buffer containing the colour on the material at the uv coordinate, as in normal deferred rendering.

EDIT: It would probably be practical in the circumstances you have described, with multiple (e.g. glow, diffuse, gloss, specular...) buffers to use these as textures, and only load one set for each material. However it will only save a small amount of bandwidth, as a normal setup would just require screen-sized textures, compared to the material textures you are suggesting. Also there would probably be a loss in performance due to switching multiple textures for every material.

Comment: huge buffers for the textures? no the textures would be passed in as needed, Pirate Material? pass in pirate textures. Dinosaur Material? pass in dinosaur textures. They wouldn't all be stuffed in at once.

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you are suggesting. Do you want to render UV coordinates and material IDs to a buffer, and then repeatedly do a pass over this for **each material** with the necessary texture? I can't quite see in what way this method would be an improvement.

Comment: normal calculations and pixel for pixel culling handled in a deferred manor, less geometry to process than a forward manor, further optimized via identifying small regions of the screen which contain the materials as to avoid overdraw.

Comment: Sorry, I mean an improvement over standard deferred rendering, rather than over forward rendering.

Comment: freedom of shaders for each material and more texture information available without adding extra buffers

Comment: I don't believe there is much performance loss by texturing pixels which may not be visible in the final render. Therefore I think you'd be better off just writing a diffuse buffer using your textures and uvs in the first pass, and you can still use multiple shaders for different materials afterwards.

Comment: the performance loss isn't in texturing the pixels its in having the extra buffers to hold the texture information (Diffuse, Specular, Glow, Decal, etc.) if you want some models to use some of these maps you need buffer space to hold them.
Rather than cutting these down to only diffuse colour and specular power, you can use the textures where they are applicable.

Comment: from what I can find, shader swapping is slower than texture swapping, so I guess I'd set a shader, run through the materials that use it, and onto the next. So my next concern would be organising materials for the least texture swaps, I've also been led to believe that texture swappings bottleneck is in changes of format and texture size, so I should probably order the materials in texture size and format too. 
The way it runs after filling the buffers is starting to look more like a z-prepassed forward renderer with less geometry, so they may be a good reference while writing the renderer.

Comment: If your lighting is purely dependent on your glow, specular... maps, you don't need to swap shaders in a deferred approach. You save the values in multiple screen-sized textures, then read these in one pass to render the lighting.

Comment: wrong, one of the key advantages of deferred rendering is the speed at which you can render multiple lights thanks to the reduced overdraw and geometry complexity, but shader limitations stop you from having multiple types of lights and lighting models in 1 shader (more so as I'm using DX9 for compatibilities sake). But my main concern is the over use of buffers, using so many large buffers is a bottleneck in itself so you have to cut out texture information to fit it all in. Drop the glow, AO maps, Specular Colour, Decals, etc. severely limiting the variation in a scene.